# Distribution of random seeds generated by std::seed_seq class

Tags: c++, random

While I understand that std::seed_seq should be used to generate a random seed for a C++ random number generator to generate e.g. uniformly distributed random numbers, I am curious how uniform is the random seed generated by std::seed_seq, given different sequences of 32 bit integers to construct an seed_seq instance.

In the documentation it's said to "produce values distributed over the entire 32-bit range even if the consumed values are close" but didn't talk about the distribution. I want to use std::seed_seq directly as a integer random number generator, using the sequence as a seed, and it's nice to know the distribution.

Comment: Generators are designed to generate sequences of random numbers. `std""seed_seq` is not.

Comment: You are right. But I think I just need a hash algo that takes a sequence of integers as input and an integer as output, and the seed_seq looks like a good candidate. Ideally I'd just use the output integer as a random number for some other tasks

Comment: A hash algorithm isn't just some random transformation; it has to be designed carefully to account for the properties of the input. `std::seed_seq` is not designed to be a hash function.

Comment: if you want to hash a sequence of integers use boost::hash_combine. if you dont want to include boost headers, cut and paste hash_combine into your code. you can find implementations of it by searching stackoverflow

Comment: The algorithm used by `generate` is listed in the language specification, and also on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq/generate).